# $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x^{\frac{1}{x+6}}-1\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x^{\frac{1}{x+6}}-1\right)$$

I've been trying to solve the limit for quite some time, though I keep coming up short. I've figured that maybe it is possible to use Puiseux series, but I can't apply it for now. Can anyone break down that method or, perhaps, suggest something simpler?

Comment: observe that $x^{1/x}=e^{\frac1x\ln x}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the fact that 
$$
x^{\frac{1}{x+6}} = e^{\frac{\ln x}{x+6}}$$
and then apply l'Hopital's rule.

Answer (score 2):

For $x>0$,

$$x^{\frac {1}{x+6}}-1=e^{\ln (x)\frac {1}{x+6}}-1$$

$$=e^{\frac{x}{x+6}\frac {\ln (x)}{x}}-1. $$

using fact that
$$\lim_{+\infty}\frac {\ln (x)}{x}=0$$
and
$$\lim_{+\infty}\frac {x}{x+6}=1,$$

we find your limit $e^0-1=0$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x^{\frac{1}{x+6}}-1\right) &= \lim_{x\to\infty}x^{\frac{1}{x+6}} - 1\\
&= \exp\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x+6}\right)-1\\
&= \exp\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}\right)-1\quad\text{(L'Hospital's Rule)}\\
&=\exp(0) - 1\\
&=1 - 1\\
&=0.
\end{align*}